# Strcmp gives segmentation Fault

Tags: c, strcmp, fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct station 
{
    char * name;
    struct station * destinations;
    struct station * next;
} station;
struct station * findStation(station * stations, char * name)
{
    if(stations = NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        station * temp;
        for(temp = station; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        {
            if(strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0)
            {
                return temp;
            }
        }
    return NULL;  
    }
}
void addStation(station ** stations, char * name)
{
    if(findStation(*stations, name) == NULL)
    {
        station * newstation;
        char name1[32];
        strcpy(name1, name);
        newstation = (station *)malloc(sizeof(station));
        newstation->name = &name1[0];
        if(*stations = NULL)
        {
            *stations = newstation;
        }
        else
        {
            newstation->next = *stations;
            *stations = newstation;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Station %s already exists.", name);
    }
}
void main(void)
{
    station * stations = NULL;
    stations = (station *)malloc(sizeof(station));
    char name[32], ch;
    strcpy(name, "Eindhoven");
    int h = 1;
    while(h == 1)
    {
        printf("Command (s/d/p/r/f/q): ");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 's':
                printf("Station: ");
                scanf("%s", name);
                addStation(&stations, &name[0]);
                break;
            case 'q':
                h = 0;
                break;
            case 'p':

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write a program for school that makes a linked list of train stations and it's destinations. This piece of code gives me Segmentation Fault at "if(strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0)" (Line 23). I've been trying to fix this for like 5 hours but nothing works :(. Does anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: `stations == NULL`

Comment: `for(temp = stations; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)` Did you even compile the code?

Comment: @coderredoc I don't see why this shouldn't compile? But it misses the last node ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: `temp = station` and station is a type.

Comment: @coderredoc ah, missing `s`, didn't see that ... and fixing it in your comment made it **less** obvious ;)

Comment: @coderredoc yeah sorry I had it with the s before when it gave the segmentation fault. Without the s it doesn't compile indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically setting `stations = NULL` and then doing something dereferencing it using `temp`. That's why the seg fault. Don't blame `strcmp`

```
if(stations == NULL) // you were assigning here. 
{
    printf("ERROR");
    return NULL;
}
```

And also

`for(temp = stations; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)`

#### Few things to note (Good practice)

Don't cast the return type of `malloc`. 
Also check the return value of `malloc`. Try to read reference of `malloc` and you would understand why.

Comment: This might also be non-obvious to the OP. Explicitly point out it's the ages old confusing assignment (`=`) with comparison (`==`) bug ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen.: Yes I was doing that in the mean time.

Comment: @coderredoc I see it now, and it helped. Thank you so much!